# Excel Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, xlsx, openpyxl

I extracted informations from ERP database of my company and with these data I have to add them to a sheet already created. But unfortunately my problem is being in how to use these commands.. The `openpyxl` documentation is not help me :(

This is an example of my sheet.

[image]

```
import sys
import datetime
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data = datetime.datetime.now()

wb = load_workbook('/home/multipla/Documentos/test.xlsx')
ws = wb.active


for i in ws['B3':'F12']:
 for j in i:
  print j
```

@Edit:

Write these cell "Hands On":

```
ws["B3"].value = '2324'
ws["C3"].value = 'Patty'
ws["D3"].value = ''
ws["E3"].value = "YES"
ws["F3"].value = "Reading"
```

Tried to automatize that process, by making a For Loop to go through each cell and write them...

@Edit2
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need help with? I can't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I edited it, please check if it is understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of dictionaries with your properties, that is:

```
object_1 = dict()
object_1['ID'] = 1337
object_1['NAME'] = 'Pencil'
...
object_2 = dict()
object_2['ID'] = 1338
object_2['NAME'] = 'Eraser'
...

object_list = list()
object_list.append(object_1)
object_list.append(object_2)
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
def add_object(ob, row):
    ws.cell(column=2, row=row).value = ob['ID']
    ws.cell(column=3, row=row).value = ob['NAME']
    ws.cell(column=4, row=row).value = ob['Y']
    ws.cell(column=5, row=row).value = ob['X']
    ws.cell(column=6, row=row).value = ob['ISSUE']

def add_object_list(ob_list):
    for i, ob in enumerate(ob_list):
        add_object(ob, i + 3)

add_object_list(object_list)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I edited my question, please see if it will clarify it!

Comment: @TMoraes I think I understand now, and I've edited my answer. See if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pedro.. I will test it

Comment: Hi Pedro, took a bit long but I got.. occurred another question, Let's assume 1,2 ROWs are merged and "Y" "X" became two subelements of "Letter" field.. @Updated my question with a picture

Comment: @TMoraes please change your question back as it was originally and open another question. People searching who read your question and then my answer would be confused as they're different things.